# Размер переменных типа boolean и byte

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Как следует из названия переменной типа `byte`, её размер равен одному байту. И, действительно,

```
sizeof(byte);
```

Вернёт 1. Но и

```
sizeof(boolean);
```

также возвращает 1, хотя, теоретически, `boolean` хранит один бит информации. На переменную нельзя выделить дробное число байт, или что?

Comment: собственно так в доках: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu5.html#x27-280003.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же, как `char` или `byte`, boolean занимает 1 байт (8 бит), чтобы хранить значения 1 или 0, `true`/`false`.

Булев тип данных может быть реализован и храниться в памяти с использованием только одного бита, но, обычно, используется минимальная адресуемая ячейка памяти (байт или машинное слово), как более эффективная, с точки зрения быстродействия единица хранения при работе с регистрами процессора и оперативной памятью.

**P.S.** в некоторых языках резервируется 2 байта.

Comment: там еще двух и четырех байтные булы есть :)

Comment: Скинь пожалуйста ссылку на 4 байтные булы. Благодарю.

Comment: Минусующим ответ предлагаю указать, в чём он неверен, или написать свой. Спасибо.

Comment: @MaksymMalishchuk, ссылка на документацию под вопросом

Comment: Хорошо, вижу, про ЛонгБул, но автор спросил тип значения boolean. sizeof(boolean)

Comment: Не совсем корректна фраза про значения 0 и 1, если берем общее определение, а не только для FreePascal. Разные языки хранят True по разному. Сходятся только в одном: False - это 0. А вот True в Delphi = -1($FF), во FreePascal и в C(емнип) = 1($1). Но это установка значения. А вот проверка (сравнение) ведется именно по единственно определенному условию (ее берет на себя компилятор): 0 = False, не 0 = True, иначе была бы невозможна стыковка с другими языками.

Answer (score 0):

В одном байте можно хранить 8 переменных типа "boolean".
Но надо отслеживать состояния всех 8 переменных в каждый момент времени.
Но это для "извращенцев".

Comment: Именно переменных - нельзя. Можно хранить 8 булевых (однобитных) значений в однобайтовой переменной.